# How to use dagger 2 in a android library project

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have a Core Android Library where I'm defining number of interfaces and its default implementations. All of them are exposed by CoreModule which is defined in CoreComponent.`

Core module

```
@Module
public class CoreModule {

@Provides
public IAuthenticationViewExtension provideToolsViewExtension() {
    return new AuthenticationViewExtension();
}
@Provides
public ISettingsViewExtension provideISettingsViewExtension() {
    return new SettingsViewExtension();
}
}
```

Core component

```
@Component( modules = {CoreModule.class})
public interface CoreComponent {
CoreComponent coreComponent();
void inject(BaseLauncher baseLauncher);
ISettingsViewExtension iSettingsViewExtension();
}
```

All implementations are injected only in Core library.

There is also a Ui library which is dependent on Core library. Additionally, Ui library can provide a custom implementation to some of interfaces defined in Core library.

```
├── Ui Library
  └── Core Library
└── Core Library
```

In order to achieve the goal I have created a custom @component and @module in Ui library

```
@Component(dependencies = {UiComponent.class}, 
modules = {UiModule.class})
public interface UiComponent {
}

@Module
public class DemoUiModule {
@Provides
public IAuthenticationViewExtension provideToolsViewExtension() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationViewExtension();
}
}
```

I think that the best solution to provide a custom implementation to Core library is be using a Subcomponent but, unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible because the Core Library has no visibility to the other libraries (Ui library and it's @component) , so I can't inject any of custom implementations in Core library.
Any help?

Comment: dagger 2 is a very conservative design idea, what exactly is your question, as in links etc

Comment: In order to have an access to any custom implementation in Core library, I have to create a instance of UiComponent in Core library, right?  However  Core Library has no visibility to the other libraries (Ui library and it's @component). So how I can provide custom implementation to Core library?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: You might be interested in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929260/injecting-application-context-in-library-module-with-dagger-2?noredirect=1#comment85206110_47929260