# How to get Component already initialized with Application context

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I just started using dagger2 and in spite of having read and documented myself to get the main ideas, I don't understand which would be the proper way of injecting the application's context.

I know that there are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929260/injecting-application-context-in-library-module-with-dagger-2/49100474) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684111/how-to-provide-context-with-dagger2) but this uses AndroidInjector and I'm getting even more lost. What I would like to understand is once the ContextComponent has been initialised and is a Singleton, how can I retrieve the instance of ContextComponent (that contains the Application's context) in order to call ContextComponent.getSharedPreferenceSpecific() and get an instance of SharedPreferenceManagerSpecific initialised with the Application's context?

The are the classes I have created, SharedPreferenceManagerSpecific it's just to understand how to inject a context to a class.

The error I get when the code of activity is executed i:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amgdeveloper.articleReader/com.amgdeveloper.articleReader.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.amgdeveloper.articleReader.dagger.ContextModule must be set
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)

ContextModule.kt

```
@Module
class ContextModule(private val app: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app

}
```

ContextComponent.tk

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ContextModule::class])
interface ContextComponent {
    fun getSharedPreferenceSpecific ():SharedPreferenceManagerSpecific

    fun inject (application: MyApplication)

    fun inject (application: MainActivity)
```

MyApplication.kt

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerContextComponent.builder().contextModule(ContextModule(this)).build()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

 val component = DaggerContextComponent.builder().build()
    val sharedPreference = component.getSharedPreferenceSpecific()
    }

}
```

SharedPreferenceManagerSpecific.kt

```
public class SharedPreferenceManagerSpecific () {
    lateinit var myContext : Context

    @Inject constructor( context: Context) : this() {
        myContext=context
    }

    fun saveIntoSharedPreferences(){
    ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger doesn't store component instances anywhere.  Not even `@Singleton` components: as far as Dagger is concerned, `@Singleton` is just another scope.  In order to create a component in your `Application` class and use it in your `Activity` class, you will need to store it somewhere yourself.

In most Android apps using Dagger, the component is stored in the `Application`:

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {
    
    // You could set a lateinit var in onCreate instead
    // if you don't use any ContentProviders.
    val component by lazy {
        DaggerContextComponent.builder().contextModule(ContextModule(this)).build()
    }
    
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val component = (application as MyApplication).component
        val sharedPreference = component.getSharedPreferenceSpecific()
    }

}
```